# Time complexity of random.sample

Tags: python, time-complexity

In another thread, I saw the time complexity of a binary-heap weighted random sample is equal to O(n * log(m)) where n is the number of choices and m is the number of nodes to choose from.

I was wondering about the time complexity of an unweighted random sample which is used by Python as random.sample. Is the time complexity simply O(n) or is it something else entirely?

Comment: It might be illuminating to read the [source code for the `random` module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab500b297900/Lib/random.py). The `random.sample()` function is defined on line 267.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python source: [`random.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab500b297900/Lib/random.py#l267) (line 267).

Here's the relevant bit:

```
   315             selected = set()
   316             selected_add = selected.add
   317             for i in range(k):
   318                 j = randbelow(n)
   319                 while j in selected:
   320                     j = randbelow(n)
   321                 selected_add(j)
   322                 result[i] = population[j]
```

It basically "rolls the dice" for a random index into `population`. If it gets an index that's already in the set `selected`, it re-rolls. Rinse, lather and repeat `k` times (where `k` is the number of samples you asked for.)

It appears to be `O(n)` in the size of the requested number of samples. There are some optimisations for small sets, but the meat of the thing is the main loop above.

---

Edit:

I believe line 305-313 are a special case for when the number of samples requested, `k`, is a large proportion of the total population `n`. Instead of rolling for random elements from the entire population (and re-rolling if we collide with an element we already selected), we explicitly maintain a list of elements we have yet to select. We are guaranteed to get a new element every time, but the tradeoff is that we have to maintain the list.

If I'm interpreting this wrong, feel free to comment below.

```
   303         result = [None] * k
   304         setsize = 21        # size of a small set minus size of an empty list
   305         if k > 5:
   306             setsize += 4 ** _ceil(_log(k * 3, 4)) # table size for big sets
   307         if n <= setsize:
   308             # An n-length list is smaller than a k-length set
   309             pool = list(population)
   310             for i in range(k):         # invariant:  non-selected at [0,n-i)
   311                 j = randbelow(n-i)
   312                 result[i] = pool[j]
   313                 pool[j] = pool[n-i-1]   # move non-selected item into vacancy
   314         else:
   315             selected = set()
   316             selected_add = selected.add
   317             for i in range(k):
   318                 j = randbelow(n)
   319                 while j in selected:
   320                     j = randbelow(n)
   321                 selected_add(j)
   322                 result[i] = population[j]
   323         return result
```

Comment: I don't think this is O(n). When you try to sample close to n elements from an n-element list, then `selected` fills up, causing more and more re-rolls of the die to be needed to find a new index. I'm not exactly sure about the complexity of that, but my hunch is that the expected time of the inner loop is O(n), causing the whole thing to be quadratic.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be `O(k)` as you say, due to the `while` loop. In fact, if `k` is close to `n` then this will take `O(n*logn)` in average. The worst-case performance is infinite of course.

Comment: @larsmans: The worst case is if you select `n` elements from a population of `n`. I believe the code has a special case for that, which maintains a "pool of items remaining" (so there are no "cache misses") instead of a "list of items already drawn". I can't quite grok what it's trying to do, though.

Comment: I don't see that case in the code. I do see special cases based on some magic constants, which seem to exploit deep knowledge of Python's collection implementations.

Comment: @larsmans: see edit for my interpretation. Every chance that I'm wrong, of course.

Comment: Hmm, seems you're right. I still don't entirely follow the `setsize` calculation, but the pool selection algorithm seems linear, assuming constant-time `randbelow`.

Comment: @larsmans: `randbelow()` appears to support bigints, so it's probably logarithmic in the size of `n`.

Comment: @Li-aungYip: but there's an upper bound on the maximum size of a Python collection (and I think the max size of a Python `int` reflects it).

Answer (score 1):

Source : https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab500b297900/Lib/random.py

This answer is similar to the one of Li-aung Yip above, but I think the precisions can be important for certain applications.

With a population of size `n` and a sample of size `k`, the complexity can be affected by the type of the input for the population : If the population is a set, line 296 of [random.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab500b297900/Lib/random.py) copies it to a tuple, which is `O(n)`, no matter what is `n` or `k`. If it is a sequence, no pre-treatment is necessary.

Afterwards, if `k` is large enough (see below), random.sample uses the following loop (line 305-313 of [random.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab500b297900/Lib/random.py)), which is `O(n)` again because of the copy of the population.

```
    if k > 5:
        setsize += 4 ** _ceil(_log(k * 3, 4)) # table size for big sets
    if n <= setsize:
        # An n-length list is smaller than a k-length set
        pool = list(population)
        for i in range(k):         # invariant:  non-selected at [0,n-i)
            j = randbelow(n-i)
            result[i] = pool[j]
            pool[j] = pool[n-i-1]   # move non-selected item into vacancy
```

The only hope for an average-case complexity different from `O(n)` is when `k` is sufficiently small such that the following loop is used :

```
else:
    selected = set()
    selected_add = selected.add
    for i in range(k):
        j = randbelow(n)
        while j in selected:
            j = randbelow(n)
        selected_add(j)
        result[i] = population[j]
```

which seems to be `O(k)` in average-case, but I'm not sure on how to prove it. Feel free to comment if I made a mistake.